# Database for every second write

Tags: database, statistics

Which database(SQL/NoSQL) is the best for statistics's site? Every 1 second will be write about 100-200 lines, only numbers, for example It can be financial stocks. {Sorry if this is bad question for this site}

Comment: It greatly depends on what exactly you need. Writing 100-200 values in one transaction is ridiculous for every database on even the cheapest hardware. Writing 100-200 values when ACID is not important is likewise trivial, even in 200 transactions. Doing 100-200 independent ACID transactions can be daunting for a system with spinning disks, even with expensive hardware.

Comment: The choice of database technology needs to also be based on how the data will be used.  If you are not ever using the data, you don't need to store it at all.  How will the data be queried?

Comment: We have got a good hw, we will buy better later. I don't know a lot of about data, some data from financial exchange, prices, etc... I think it will write only 8 hours daily. I need save it because it will create historical statistics and some math things

Answer (score 0):

MySQL would make it rock-solid, because you wouldn't lose any of your lines. Also, writing a query to perform math on those columns would be extremely easy with MySQL.

A NoSQL solution, like MongoDB, would be able to scale much better assuming these rows will be INSERTed forever and ever making the collection very large. MySQL would take up more disk space.

If you NEED atomic operations because, for example, you can't lose any of the rows, MySQL is your best bet.

Comment: Note that MySQL is only rock-solid if InnoDB is used (which is default beginning with MySQL 5.5). MyIsam is of course much faster, but not suitable for data which itself or its consistency is important in some way.